# Code splitting in a javascript library that is used as both a script tag and npm

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, vite

I have a javascript library that I have published to npm but is also usable as a regular script tag. That is, to use my library you can either do:

```
<script src="dist/my-lib-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or include it in `package.json` and import it:

```
import myLib from "my-lib";
```

I have a fairly simple webpack build for the minimized version with the relevant part being:

```
output: {
  library: {
    amd: myLib,
    root: myLib,
    commonjs: myLib
  },
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
  globalObject: 'this',
  filename: `my-lib-min.js`,
},
```

and I point to it in `package.json` for the npm version:

```
"main": "dist/my-lib-min.js",
```

That works ok but I want to add code splitting. Many uses of the library don't require a couple of the large features so I'd like to make them optional. That is, I'd like my library to be used something like:

```
<script src="dist/my-lib-core-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="dist/my-lib-feature-1-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="dist/my-lib-feature-2-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you want to use everything but just require the first line if you want a smaller download. And for npm it should also do code splitting.

I keep going around in circles about how to do the architecture of this. What I keep coming back to is:

Create an exhaustive combination of min files. That is, output `my-lib-core-min.js`, `my-lib-core-and-feature-1-min.js`, `my-lib-core-and-feature-2-min.js`, `my-lib-core-and-features-1-and-2-min.js` and have the end user just pick the version they need. This will get unwieldy when I add more features. Also, what would I point "main" to in package.json? Would I create another build that uses npm code splitting techniques?

I also was thinking of making this three separate npm packages and using peer dependencies but that still doesn't help how to manage the script tag version.

I just have the feeling there is a better solution. Plus I'm not sure how to set up the project or webpack to do the npm implementation.

Can anyone give me any insight about the direction I should go, or have some examples that would help? I saw this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/anatomy-of-js-module-systems-and-building-libraries-fadcd8dbd0e/ but it doesn't show tree splitting on the script tag side.

I'm not wedded to webpack - I wouldn't mind switching to Vite but it needs to support older browsers in production and I think Vite doesn't.

P.S. I tried to use `splitChunks`, which created the chunks successfully but the page requires all of them to be loaded so that doesn't help. That is, when I load just the core part as a script tag, the variable `window.myLib` is not set and it isn't set until I load the last chunk. Is there a way to make the other chunks optional?

Comment: have you found any solutions to this?

Comment: Sort of - I experimented with a home made plugin system and it looks like it would work, but I got distracted by more urgent things. The idea is that there is a core that contains a function that can be called to register another module and I got it pretty clean - just load the core js then the plugin and the plugin automatically calls that function. I'll post a solution when I get it checked in and open sourced. It will be a month or so.

Comment: can't wait! It would be very easier if  wecould just change the __asign fucntion that webpack brings to tie our libraries to browser "namespaces".